how to get redirect addresses
When trying to access a website from a browser, after I type the generic URL, am redirected to a more complex (different) URL.
How can I get the **redirected URL ** programmatically?
In my current program am using JS; **axios **and cheerio, but I get no response, since it doesn't reach the first URL
P.S. I could also split it into two step project if necessary
TIA
A way to get the re-directed web address.
I have tried:

Inter the URL in the forms, input="text"
Hit the Open button
it opens the redirected URL in a new tab


BUT When I go back to the original tab, I see the alert windows   "This page says.    About:blank"...... can not get the re-directed URL


I'm not sure you can do this in JavaScript. fetch() will follow the redirect rather than provide a way to return it.

Do a "XMLHttpRequest" instead of a "fetch" and check for the HTTP Status code/redirect/location header.

If you dont want to work/expirment with XMLHttpRequest, play with the fetch option redirect: 'manual'
